# How to connect to a remote SQL Server from a shared hosting account

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a shared hosting account with namecheap running an application in php 8.1. I have also enabled the extensions sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv. The hosting account is on linux.

```
    $serverName = "38.17.53.119,16301";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"chuna", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Successfuly connected.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection error.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

In the above code, I want to connect to a remote sql server on cloudclusters.io and I get the error below:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10057 [code] => 10057 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10057 [code] => 10057 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )
```

I have tested the remote connection on my localhost(Windows) and it's successful. It fails only on my hosting account.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to open the port 16301 for outgoing traffic on the hosting server.